# Is it possible to complete Shelter without losing any cubs?

Tags: shelter

I am completely new to this game and I just finished the first part. So now I am at the night part, but I lost a cub at the first part. A bird took it. I was wondering if there is a way that I can get past the bird without a cub getting caught, if so, is it possible to end the game with all the cubs? Cause I dont want to lose any cubs...

Answer (score 2):

I made it through the first two areas without losing a cub.  I lost one in the third area, and one in the final area, but I'm pretty sure that I could have avoided both losses if I had been more careful.

Based on what I saw of the levels, I'm fairly certain it's possible to complete Shelter without losing any cubs.  Be on your best guard, and keep a close eye on your young.

Comment: I am still looking for a confirmation before accepting.

Comment: @Loko Without playing through the whole game again I won't be able to do that I guess.  But like I said, I didn't see any points where I seemed forced to lose a cub.  I did the last level again and managed to avoid losing the cub I lost previously.  I'll get back to you eventually when I get a chance to play through it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I made it through to the very last level with all five cubs. But when the ending scene came the hawk took one of my babies. I could do nothing. There was no grass.  Instead of taking who the hawk was supposed to take it took a cub. I tried it two times, no matter what I did or which route I took it grabbed one of my babies anyway.

(I tried not to spoil the ending.)